# PowerPoint VBA - Switch between 16:9 and 4:3

Tags: vba, powerpoint

It's been a few years since I wrote VBA code, but I remember I wrote a makro to switch between 16:9 and 4:3, without stretching all images. However, I can't find the code and decided to have a go from scratch.

Now, what I've noticed is that while I can effectively reset the scale and position of images, all other elements also shift positions. So how can I maintain position and the scale of all elements when switching between?

It seems maybe I need to store the position of all elements before the orientation is changed. Does it mean I have to create a copy of the whole document and progmatically place each element back?

What if a user decides to switch a presentation to 4:3, saves the document, but then changes his mind and want 16:9 again? Wouldn't the original range be lost??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > So how can I maintain position and the scale of all elements when switching between?

Write about 12 miles worth of code. BTDT and sell the result as a PowerPoint add-in ;-)

But if you have a recent version of PowerPoint, it can do a reasonably good job of switching between 4:3 and 16:9 w/o distorting anything.

It'll letterbox, but I don't know how that can be avoided w/o distorting the relationship between different shapes.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. I'm supposed to sell it as a feature in a template, but seems like they'd be better suited to just buy an already existing add-in. Instead of me spending a week writing the thing, costing them more.

Comment: It actually can be done in a theme (THMX) file; if you change the proportions of slides based on one of Microsoft's supplied themes, they behave well. Unfortunately, MS has never documented how this works or released the tool they use to combine multiple themes into one THMX file. There are a few people who have the know-how/skill to do it though; try Echo Swinford at echosvoice.com Or if you want to look at an add-in, try the free demo of my Resize add-in, available at pptools.com